# Live USB version of Kali Linux GRUB issues

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, live-usb

I have installed kali linux on a 32GB USB drive, and i have a 9GB partition for persistence. Also, the Macbook Pro i am running Kali on requires the AMD GPU to be disabled, so i am using [this guide](https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/)  to disable the AMD GPU (Step 3). I want to disable it permanently, but the `/etc/default/grub` file is missing. I reinstalled GRUB 2.0 and the grub config file was there although there was an error:

```
    error: failed to get canonical path of 'overlay'
```

After editing it , i couldn't get the grub-update command to run. It says that there is no such command. And after rebooting, the file disappeared again.

Please help me with this issue. I appreciate your assistance greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

And then:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Those might help.

Comment: it says `grub-install: command not found`

Comment: @TheRealOrange Did you try it as root, like with `sudo`?

Comment: yes i was logged in as root

Comment: @TheRealOrange Take a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB "GRUB ArchWiki")

Comment: sorry, but that is for arch linux?

Comment: @TheRealOrange Its GRUB explanations mostly hold true for every distro

Comment: I understand, but i cant find anything relevant to USB live persistence installs of Linux